# Uboot adding new serial driver on arm

Tags: c, arm, u-boot

I'm trying to add my own serial driver to uboot. That what I've been achieved so far are those messages:

```
U-Boot SPL 2017.09-gdc4fd1d6eb-dirty (Dec 30 2017 - 09:13:03)
DRAM: 2048 MiB
Trying to boot from FEL
```

but that is all. I know that there should be other messages also, but there are not any.

I suspect that my serial driver is working only in uboot SPL, but after that there is "uboot device model" driver compatible needed to run. Am I right?

To register my driver in "uboot device model" I introduced two invocations:

```
U_BOOT_DEVICE(sun8i_serials) = {
        .name = "serial_sun8i",
        .platdata = &sun8i_serial_plat,
};


U_BOOT_DRIVER(serial_sun8i) = {
    .name = "serial_sun8i",
    .id = UCLASS_SERIAL,
    .ops = &sun8i_serial_ops,
    .probe = sun8i_serial_probe,
};
```

With those two structures I expected that my procedure "sun8i_serial_probe" will be executed but it isn't. In this procedure I'm just turning on some LED, but this LED is still off, so my conclusion is that it is not invocated.

What should I do to proper register my driver and achieve call to my sun8i_serial_probe procedure?

Maybe after the SPL there is another step (third program loader?) and it is working in arm virtual memory space and that is why my procedure is not able to turn on the LED?

Any suggestions?

Edit1: I discovered that proc list_bind_drivers() issues "No match for driver serial_sun8i". So seems like U_BOOT_DEVICE is working fine while U_BOOT_DRIVER for some reasons not.

Edit2: Seems like I fixed the bug. The bug was in Makefile.